# In CSV file \t (tab) is not accepting as column delimiter with php

Tags: php, mysql

Well, this is the file which i'm working to save mysql query result to .csv format. it's successfully return data but when I view the CSV file it's showing `?` mark in each `row`. It's because it's not accepting `\t` tab character as column delimiter for seperate the each column value.

How do I use `t` character in CSV and how do i show the result in each **column by column**  NOT overwrite the each column value to another column ?

What I'm expecting in CSV file is look like this :

```
--------------------------
Column 1        Column 2
-------------------------
result 1       result 2
result 1       result 2
result 1       result 2
result 1       result 2
```

But It's showing: http://propertyjungle.com.au/correct-view.gif

**csv.php file**

```
?php
$filename = 'text.csv';
header('Content-type: application/csv');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.$filename);

$host="";
$uname="";
$pass="";
$database = ""; 
$connection=mysql_connect($host,$uname,$pass); 
echo mysql_error();

//or die("Database Connection Failed");
$selectdb=mysql_select_db($database) or die("Database could not be selected");  
$result=mysql_select_db($database)
or die("database cannot be selected <br>");

$sqlagentdetails = "select * from users WHERE company_name != ''";
$rowresult = mysql_query($sqlagentdetails); 

echo "Column 1";
echo "\t";
echo "Column 2";
echo "\n";


while($row = mysql_fetch_array($rowresult, MYSQL_ASSOC))
{
    $myQuery =  mysql_query( /* query are goes to here...*/ );

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($myQuery)){  

    $postcode = "{$row['postcode']}";  
    $paddress = "{$row['paddress']}";

echo "$emailAgent";
echo "\t";
echo "$paddress";
echo "\n";

    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Sounds like a problem with Excel to me.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams I don't think It's a problem on Excel. I've another example which show the data correctly in .CSV file.

Comment: And have you compared the two?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure whether you can directly export data to `.CSV` or not but your code is working fine if you just replace it with `.XLS` . You can then convert it to `.CSV` . Hope this way it works

```
$filename = 'text.xls';
```

Comment: Recommendation will only work if you have PHP's automagic extension enabled.... rennaming a file .xls does not change the format of that file in any way whatsoever